# Decision Tree Generation for a Treeview

Tags: c#, winforms, recursion, tree, treeview

I am trying to generate a decision tree, that will be displayed in a TreeView. This is for a football game developer interface. It will allow the user to add events to particular nodes. The problem I have is generating all of the nodes. When using a linked list one can share nodes, where paths cross, but this cant be utilised in a TreeView, as the nodes get confused. I have an image here:

[image: TreeView]

As you know football is a goal event game, and once a goal is scored, I move into the next node in the tree. So a score of 0 - 0 is the starting point. That node then splits into 2 nodes (1 - 0) and (0 - 1). Once on a path the tree needs to cater for travelling down that path but also cater for 2 - 2, 3 - 2, 3 - 3, etc

So each node in the tree needs to contain all possible solutions from the previous score. I'm sure you get the idea.

The maximum score, or exit point for the recursion is defined as:
 (Home + Away) < 8

I call the recursion routine with:
Recurse(rootNode, 0, 0);

The function CreateNodeFromScore does the fancy node creation and works great.

My recursion code is here:

```
private void Recurse(TreeNode node, int iHome, int iAway) {

  if ((iHome + iAway) == 8 ) {
    return;
  }

  node.Nodes.Add( CreateNodeFromScore(iHome, iAway) );

  TreeNode nextNode = node.Nodes[0];
  Recurse(nextNode, ++iHome, iAway);
  Recurse(nextNode, iHome, ++iAway);
}

private void CreateNodeFromScore(int iHome, int iAway) {
    return new TreeNode(iHome.ToString() + " - " + iAway.ToString());
}
```

I have tried many ways to get this working, but the solution eludes me.

This is an algorithm problem rather than a gui, treeview, or C#, C++ problem. The code can be pretty much directly translated between the 2 languages.

Can any help me ?

Comment: 1) You have tagged your question [tag:c#] and [tag:c++].  Which are you actually using?  2) What GUI framework are you using?  3) *I have tried many ways to get this working, but the solution eludes me.* -- what is the **problem** you are seeing?  What doesn't work?  4) How do you initialize the `TreeVIew` and its root node?  5) Can you [edit] your question to expand it into a full [mcve]?

Comment: I am currently using C#, however the code can be pretty much directly translated into C++. This is why I used both tags. The framework is standard windows Forms. The initialisation is superfluous to the question asked. The problem is with the recursion. I only get one side of the tree being created, or all nodes hanging off 1 node. This is not a treeview problem. It is not a Node creation problem It is a problem relating to a tree where, instead of traversing each node, each node needs to be created with each "next" possible permutation. This is an algorithm problem. Thanks.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [ask] and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ which suggest that you *Help others reproduce the problem*.  If you're share a full [mcve] that shows how you initialize the tree and the problem that results, you're more likely to get help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question here, as I have figured out the answer. Interestingly, posting here has helped me re-think the problem as I think I was getting confused. My thanks to @dbc for his advice and pointers.

```
private void Recurse(TreeNode node, int iHome, int iAway) {

  if ((iHome + iAway)> 7)
    return;

  var homeNode = CreateNodeFromScore(iHome +1, iAway);
  var awayNode = CreateNodeFromScore(iHome, iAway + 1);

  node.Nodes.Add(homeNode);
  node.Nodes.Add(awayNode);

  Recurse(homeNode, iHome +1, iAway);
  Recurse(awayNode, iHome, iAway +1);

}
```

Produces this result:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsZe5.png

I hope this might be useful for others

Andrea